# Query in DynamoDB without Global Index

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple table in my DynamoDB, and I want to do a simple query, just a list where `status = active`

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('../../../../config/dynamo');

const { URI } = config;

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
  endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint(URI)
});

const params = {
  AttributeDefinitions: [{
    AttributeName: 'idPhysicalPerson',
    AttributeType: 'N'
  },
  {
    AttributeName: 'cpf',
    AttributeType: 'S'
  }],
  KeySchema: [{
    AttributeName: 'idPhysicalPerson',
    KeyType: 'HASH'
  },
  {
    AttributeName: 'cpf',
    KeyType: 'RANGE'
  }],
  ProvisionedThroughput: {
    ReadCapacityUnits: 5,
    WriteCapacityUnits: 5
  },
  TableName: 'PhysicalPerson'
};
dynamodb.createTable(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

this table contains a lot of properties, and if I want to perform a simple query, I always need to put these fields in a Global Index ?

I just want get all data that has the `active` status, but in a real application, if I have a feature like `advanced filter` where I can set a lot of properties, How this can be treated in DynamoDB whitout put all properties in Global Index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [scan feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html).

In DynamoDB that's not a recommended thing to do if you have a large dataset ([because it reads the entire dataset before returning what you want](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScanGuidelines.html#QueryAndScanGuidelines.ScanPerformance)).

You may want to do a composite sort key where all your data is available :

`cpf_otherValue_otherValue2_...`

Maybe not with all, but the 2/3 most used and query with `begins_with` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression

Or maybe if you have advanced search feature it would be better to have an ElasticSearch cluster instead of DynamoDB : DynamoDB is a Key/Value store that support large dataset and high throughput, advanced search feature is not a common use case : but again, if you dont have too much data, it can work.